# django2/angular4 url (re_path and path)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i can`t solve problem with new django url path...
when i try to navigate to another url like http://localhost:8000/notexistsurl/

```
#file urls.py
path('api/', admin.site.urls),
path('', TemplateViews.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

this will show django Page not found (404)

and if i use old re_path syntax:

```
#file urls.py
path('api/', admin.site.urls),
re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

this will show angular4 Page not found (404)

how can I use (r'^.*') syntax with new Django url (path?

Comment: remove `r'^api/'` from `path(r'^api/', admin.site.urls),`. Just use `path('api', admin.site.urls),`.

Comment: this is copy past miss sorry, this miss is not relevant to my question.thx